# How to replace inline event handlers (onmousedown, onmouseover, onmouseout,...) containing parameters to comply with CSP rules?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, geonames

I have been trying all day & searched everywhere for a solution. It hasn't been really successful, and honestly after years browsing stackoverflow that's the first time I post looking for help. :-)

I recently implemented a strict CSP. I forked JSONscriptRequest class of Jason Levitt to secure more the dynamic  tag (http://www.geonames.org/export/jsr_class.js) with nonce.
I appreciate using this because I really customized and used it a lot (a lot of modules depends on it).

Originally, the script was outputing this in HTML :

```
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId0" onmousedown="suggestBoxMouseDown(0)" onmouseover="suggestBoxMouseOver(0)" onmouseout="suggestBoxMouseOut(0)">...</div>
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId1" onmousedown="suggestBoxMouseDown(1)" onmouseover="suggestBoxMouseOver(1)" onmouseout="suggestBoxMouseOut(1)">...</div>(and so on, depending on the number of results.)
...
```

They all have the same class (suggestions). I know i can do this to replace the inline event handlers, but without any parameters :

```
document.getElementById("placeInput").addEventListener("input", postalCodeLookup)
```

I tried doing this

```
document.getElementById("placeInput").addEventListener("change", function() {

var suggestions = document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions');  

console.log(suggestions);

for (i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
suggestions[i].addEventListener("mousedown", suggestBoxMouseDown([i]));
suggestions[i].addEventListener("mouseover", suggestBoxMouseOver([i]));
suggestions[i].addEventListener("mouseout", suggestBoxMouseOut([i]));
}

});`
```

Annnd it has been a complete failure again.

I don't know how to pass variable to my functions as easily that we could before.

Concerned functions :

```
// remove highlight on mouse out event
function suggestBoxMouseOut(obj) {
    document.getElementById('pcId'+ obj).className = 'suggestions';
} 
// the user has selected a place name from the suggest box  
function suggestBoxMouseDown(obj) {
    closeSuggestBox();
    var postalcodeInput = document.getElementById("postalcodeInput");
    var placeInput = document.getElementById("placeInput");
    var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude");
    var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
    postalcodeInput.value = postalCodes[obj].postalCode;
    placeInput.value = postalCodes[obj].placeName + " (" + postalCodes[obj].postalCode + ", " + postalCodes[obj].countryCode + ")";
    latitude.value = postalCodes[obj].lat;
    longitude.value = postalCodes[obj].lng;  
}
// function to highlight places on mouse over event
function suggestBoxMouseOver(obj) {
    document.getElementById('pcId'+ obj).className = 'suggestionMouseOver';
}
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Soem quick ideas to refactor the code:

1. Implement rules for classes `.suggestions` and `suggestionMouseOver` with `.sugestions` and the [`:hover` pseudo class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) in CSS:

   ```
    .suggestions {
        ... rules for mouse not over ...
    }
    .suggestions:hover { 
        ... rule changes for when when hovering over *.suggestions ...
    }
   ```

   This should remove the need to monitor `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on `.suggestion` class elements simply to change styling. (Note `mouseover` and `mouseout` can fire over when mousing over child elements of the hover class.)
2. Generate a `data-` attribute on HTML elements to record the index number of the suggestion. Currently this implemented as a numeric suffix on the `id` attribute value which, while remaining a possibility, is not the cleanest solution:

   ```
   <div class="suggestions" data-num="0">...</div>
   <div class="suggestions" data-num="1">...</div> <!-- and so on -->
   ```
3. Although event processing could be delegated by providing a single event on a common parent element and looking at the `target` attribute of events fired, the straight forward approach may still be to stay with an event listener on each `div` element:

   ```
   function sugestionMouseDown( event) {
       let suggestionDiv = event.currentTarget;
       let suggestionNumber = suggestionDiv.dataset.num;
       // process parameters suggestionDiv and suggestionNumber
       // ...
   }
   Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions') )
   .forEach( div => div.addEventListener("mousedown", suggestionMouseDown));
   ```

Comment: Many thanks @traktor53. Following your advice, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @traktor53 good advices, this is what I came up with.

Note for futures researchers on stackoverflow : the goal is to replace the javascript inline event handlers containing an argument (ex.: `onmouseout(0)`, ...). The reason behind is to comply with the Content Security Policy (CSP) which is not allowing inline script for obvious reasons. I apply the code below on a custom jsr_class.js fetching results on GeoNames API.

### HTML

It's dynamically generated as this :

```
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId0" data-num="0"> Vannes - (56000) &nbsp;FR</div>
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId1" data-num="1"> Vannes - (56001 CEDEX) &nbsp;FR</div>
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId2" data-num="2"> Vannes - (56002 CEDEX) &nbsp;FR</div>
<div class="suggestions" id="pcId3" data-num="3"> Vannes - (56003 CEDEX) &nbsp;FR</div>
```

### CSS

The goal here is to replace the old onmouseover & onmouseout functions

```
.suggestions { 
    font-size: 14;
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

.suggestions:hover { 
    font-size: 14;
    background: #456ae7; 
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

### Javascript

I didn't wanted to modify my original function for pratical reasons, I know cleaner methods can be done.

```
function triggerMouseDown( event) {
let suggestionDiv = event.currentTarget;
let suggestionNumber = suggestionDiv.dataset.num;

suggestBoxMouseDown(suggestionNumber);
}

document.getElementById("placeInput").addEventListener("change", function() {

Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('suggestions') )
.forEach( div => div.addEventListener("click", triggerMouseDown));
});
```